# Azure Cosmos query to convert into List

Tags: list, azure, azure-cosmosdb

This is my JSON data, which is stored into cosmos db

```
{
    "id": "e064a694-8e1e-4660-a3ef-6b894e9414f7",
    "Name": "Name",
    "keyData": {
        "Keys": [
            "Government",
            "Training",
            "support"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a query to eliminate the `keyData` and get only the `Keys` (like below)

```
{
    "userid": "e064a694-8e1e-4660-a3ef-6b894e9414f7",
    "Name": "Name",
    "Keys"  :[
        "Government",
        "Training",
        "support"
    ]
}
```

So far I tried the query like

```
SELECT c.id,k.Keys  FROM c
JOIN k in c.keyPhraseBatchResult
```

Which is not working.

**Update 1:**

After trying with the ***Sajeetharan*** now I can able to get the result, but the issue it producing another JSON inside the Array.

Like

```
{
    "id": "ee885fdc-9951-40e2-b1e7-8564003cd554",
    "keys": [
        {
            "serving": "Government"
        },
        {
            "serving": "Training"
        },
        {
            "serving": "support"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there is any way that extracts only the Array without having `key` `value` pari again?

```
{
    "userid": "e064a694-8e1e-4660-a3ef-6b894e9414f7",
    "Name": "Name",
    "Keys"  :[
        "Government",
        "Training",
        "support"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one,

```
SELECT C.id, ARRAY(SELECT VALUE serving FROM serving IN C.keyData.Keys) AS Keys FROM C
```

Comment: thanks, Sajeetharan for your answer, I tried your answer and facing other issue,Pls see my *Update 1* in the OP. could you pls help me

Comment: Try this instead: SELECT
    C.id,
    ARRAY(SELECT VALUE serving FROM serving IN C.keyData.Keys) AS Keys
FROM C

Comment: Thanks Krishnan and sajeetharan for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please use cosmos db stored procedure to implement your desired format based on the @Sajeetharan's sql.

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT C.id,ARRAY(SELECT serving FROM serving IN C.keyData.Keys) AS keys FROM C',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var map = {};
             for(var i=0;i<feed.length;i++){
                 var keyArray = feed[i].keys;
                 var array = [];
                 for(var j=0;j<keyArray.length;j++){
                    array.push(keyArray[j].serving)
                 }
                 feed[i].keys = array;
             }
            response.setBody(feed);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jaygong upvoted since sajeetharan updated query worked now. But with your solution I learned how to achieve this using storproc. Thanks again !

Comment: @Jayendran Thank you.@sajeetharan's solution is very nice for you.